# Null Reference exception with ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have just upgraded from ASP.NET MVC Beta to the newly released V1 - however suddenly the code below is throwing a null reference exception.  This was working fine before with no problems at all.  Does anyone have any ideas?

```
<%= Html.ActionLink<Website.Web.Controllers.PageController>(x => x.Edit(2), "Edit") %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like you are using ActionLink extensions from the MvcFutures assembly.  Have you updated to the newest futures release as well?  Note that I don't use MvcFutures so I don't know if the latest vesion works with the RTW version of ASP.NET MVC.